# Find in what polygon is each point

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, polygon, point

I am new to Python, so I apologize for the rudimentary programming skills, I am aware I am using a bit too much "loop for" (coming from Matlab it is dragging me down).

I have millions of points (timestep, long, lat, pointID) and hundreds of irregular non-overlapping polygons (vertex_long,vertex_lat,polygonID).[points and polygons format sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGjrg.jpg)

I want to know what polygon contains each point.

I was able to do it this way:

```
from matplotlib import path
def inpolygon(lon_point, lat_point, lon_poly, lat_poly):
   shape = lon_point.shape
   lon_point = lon_point.reshape(-1)
   lat_point = lat_point.reshape(-1)
   lon_poly = lon_poly.values.reshape(-1)
   lat_poly = lat_poly.values.reshape(-1)
   points = [(lon_point[i], lat_point[i]) for i in range(lon_point.shape[0])]
   polys = path.Path([(lon_poly[i], lat_poly[i]) for i in range(lon_poly.shape[0])])
   return polys.contains_points(points).reshape(shape)
```

And then

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Areas_Lon = Areas.iloc[:,0]
Areas_Lat = Areas.iloc[:,1]
Areas_ID  = Areas.iloc[:,2]
Unique_Areas = np.unique(Areas_ID)

Areas_true=np.zeros((Areas_ID.shape[0],Unique_Areas.shape[0]))
for i in range(Areas_ID.shape[0]):
    for ii in range(Unique_Areas.shape[0]):
        Areas_true[i,ii]=(Areas_ID[i]==Unique_Areas[ii])

Areas_Lon_Vertex=np.zeros(Unique_Areas.shape[0],dtype=object)
Areas_Lat_Vertex=np.zeros(Unique_Areas.shape[0],dtype=object)
for i in range(Unique_Areas.shape[0]):
    Areas_Lon_Vertex[i]=(Areas_Lon[(Areas_true[:,i]==1)])
    Areas_Lat_Vertex[i]=(Areas_Lat[(Areas_true[:,i]==1)])

import f_inpolygon as inpolygon
Areas_in=np.zeros((Unique_Areas.shape[0],Points.shape[0]))
for i in range (Unique_Areas.shape[0]):
    for ii in range (PT.shape[0]):
        Areas_in[i,ii]=(inpolygon.inpolygon(Points[ii,2], Points[ii,3], Areas_Lon_Vertex[i], Areas_Lat_Vertex[i]))
```

This way the final outcome Areas_in [Areas_in format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD8P4.png) contains as many rows as polygons and as many columns as points, where every column is true=1 at the row where the point is relative to polygon index (1st given polygon ID --> 1st row, and so).

The code works but very slowly for what it is supossed to do. When locating points in a regular grid or within a point radius I have succesfully tried implement a KDtree, what increases dramatically the speed, but I can`t do the same or whatever faster to irregular non-overlapping polygons.

I have seen some related questions but rather than asking for what polygons a point is were about whether a point is inside a polygon or not.

Any idea please?

Comment: Have you considered using [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/)?

Comment: Please avoid posting images on SO. Try posting a minimal reproducible code with sample input and desired output. Thank you

Comment: Sample input are in above images and desired output would be something like: Point1-Timestep1 = is in AreaX; Point2-Timestep1 = is in AreaX; ...; Point1-TimeStepN = is in AreaX, Point2-TimestepN = is in AreaX; ...; PointN-TimestepN = is in AreaX.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Geopandas Spatial join?

install the Package using pip
`pip install geopandas`
or conda
`conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

then you should able to read the data as GeoDataframe

```
import geopandas 

df = geopandas.read_file("file_name1.csv") # you can read shp files too.
right_df = geopandas.read_file("file_name2.csv") # you can read shp files too.

# Convert into geometry column 
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])] # Coordinate reference system : WGS84

crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
# Creating a Geographic data frame 
left_df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

Then you can apply the sjoin

```
jdf = geopandas.sjoin(left_df, right_df, how='inner', op='intersects', lsuffix='left', rsuffix='right')
```

the option in op are:

- intersects
- contains
- within

All should do the same in your case when you joining two geometry columns of type Polygon and Point

Comment: Thank you Abi2021, it worked!! I coludn't answer any sooner because I had some troubles to install geopandas (eventually I had to downgrade conda version). With geopandas sjoin works faster ... however I wonder if there was the chance to apply a query tree ... anyway thanks for your help.