# How to check if a polygon contanis a point

Tags: geopandas

Hi i have a 4 shapfiles, each one with one polygon, i want to check inside which one of them lies my point.
I have this as a output

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
import geopandas as gpd
        from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
        import fiona
        from fiona.crs import from_epsg
        
        newdata = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
        
        newdata['geometry'] = None
        
        
        x = 5880038.22
        y = 7502893.22
        p_1 = Point(y,x)
        
        newdata.loc[0, 'geometry'] = p_1
        
        
        newdata.crs = from_epsg(2178)
        
        outfp = "point.shp"
        
        newdata.to_file(outfp)
        
        paths = ['strefa_5.shp', 'strefa_6.shp', 'strefa_7.shp', 'strefa_8.shp']
        EPSG = [2176, 2177, 2178, 2179]
        
        for i in paths:
            s = gpd.read_file(i)
            for j in EPSG:
                s.crs = from_epsg(j)
                newdata.crs = from_epsg(j)
                if s['geometry'].contains(newdata['geometry']):
                    a = i[7]
                    print(a)
                else:
                    continue
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find in what polygon is each point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63405079/find-in-what-polygon-is-each-point)

Comment: Your `s['geometry'].contains(newdata['geometry'])` returns _a Series of dtype(bool) with value True for each aligned geometry that contains other_ - https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.contains.html That error suggests you to use one of the listed methods to get a truth value for your if-statement, as you (should) have only a single element in your resulting Series, you could use `.bool()` , like `if s['geometry'].contains(newdata['geometry']).bool() :` - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.bool.html

Comment: By any chance, are you testing which projection bounds of four _Poland CS2000_ zones is valid for your point coordinates? CRS definition already includes bounds, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394744/how-to-check-which-geometries-in-a-geodataframe-are-within-the-bounds-limits-of might give you some ideas how to use those. I might be mistaken, but you also seem to assume that by setting `Geodataframe.crs` , points in geometries will be re-projected?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how the problem could be solved.
Output of s['geometry'].contains(newdata['geometry']) is

0    True
dtype: bool

so i decided to do get acces by using a index

paths = ['strefa_5.shp', 'strefa_6.shp', 'strefa_7.shp', 'strefa_8.shp']

EPSG = [2176, 2177, 2178, 2179]

```
for i in paths:
    s = gpd.read_file(i)
    for j in EPSG:
        s.crs = from_epsg(j)
        newdata.crs = from_epsg(j)
        newdata.to_file(output)
        a = s['geometry'].contains(newdata['geometry'])
        if a[0] == True:
            b = i[7]
        else:
            pass
```

Thanks for all of u for helping